# How to use settings in business/domain layer in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, settings, appsettings

I see that the preferred way to use settings is to use Options pattern, and inject `IOptions<T>` object in class where I want to use settings.

Is there any other solution how to make this work in Business/Domain layer where I don't want to reference ASP.NET Core specific DLL like the one with `IOptions<T>` infrastructure?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IConfiguration` too. This technology is evolving fast, and the best practices are constantly changing. Take for example the docs on Configuration for [2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.0), [2.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.1), [2.2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.2) and [3.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.0)

As of today, you could sensibly build ASP.NET Core apps in any of these versions.

Hitting the middle ground, say 2.1, look at [the configuration docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-2.1) and take some time to understand the many different ways of using this.

In 2.1, you can use `appSettings.json` to control settings for different deployments and different layers.

The default scaffolding adds `CreateWebHostBuilder`:

```
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
                     WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                            .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

Under the covers this calls calls `AddJsonFile` twice, once for `appsettings.json` and again for `appsettings.{Environment}.json`.

Add an `appsettings.Production.json` file to you project, and you'll get the benefits.

Then the respective appSettings file will be used based on an `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` value that can be added to project properties (or Azure Web App | Application Settings) as needed. If not supplied it will default to `Production`

Answer (score 0):

To read Configuration in in .Net Core:

```
//Sample appsettings.json



{
       "Logging": {
          "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Warning"
               }
         },
      "AllowedHosts": "*",
      "UserId": "sa",
      "UserPassword": "123",
      "ServerName": "abc"``
 }
```

Step 2 :
Download NuGet packages
-Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration,Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions
,Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json

```
  Add Class(name class whatever you want) 

       static class AppSettings
       {
          public static IConfiguration Settings { get; }
          static AppSettings()
          {
            Settings = new ConfigurationBuilder().SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()).AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();
          }
       }
```

In Business, logic read as:

```
string strUserID= AppSettings.Settings["DbUserId"].ToString()
```

Answer (score 0):

@CsharpBeginner, I believe I share your concern.

Our domain/use case layer should not know about the way configuration is injected. Therefore, I believe we should not depend on framework solutions as IOptions.

I guess the only ways to solve this are:

- to inject the configuration class itself (T in your case) without using `IOptions` or
- to use some sort of *custom* `IOptions` interface together with a custom implementation (outside of domain) which in turn uses Microsoft’s `IOptions` to pass on the configuration class.